# is sorting is same by sql query and python function in alphabatical ortder by asc?

Tags: python, sql, selenium

I have 3 values.

```
i) Test ii) test_validation iii) Test02
```

Now in sql when I fire query order by alphabatical asc- the result is
`i) Test ii) test_validation iii) Test02`
but when I use python function like-

```
listN=["Test", "test_validation", "Test02"]
sortedList=sorted(listN, key=str.casefold)
```

then result comes
`i) Test ii) Test02 iii) test_validation`

please give me proper algorithm of this type of sorting

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking for an algorithm written in SQL that replicates the behavior of Python's sort? Or are you asking for an algorithm written in Python that replicates the behavior of SQL's sort?

Comment: tell me which is proper sorting result of above question- sql side result or python function side result?

Comment: Define "proper". I'm sure both approaches have perfectly valid internal logic.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that mimic the SQL ORDER BY ASC algorithme, The lambda transforms your Underscore to a hash key:

```
listN=["a", "b", "c","_","#","@","$","%","}"]
sorted(listN,key=lambda d: d.lower().replace('_','#').replace('}','#'))
['_', '#', '}', '$', '%', '@', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

**This way you get the underscore firstly then the other characters, you can play with the replace and change the order the way you need :**

```
sorted(listN,key=lambda d: d.lower().replace('_','#'))
['Test', 'test_validation', 'Test02']
```